# How install pydantic library in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, pydantic

I'm working in a project develop with serverless framework, Flask and MongoDB. The problem it's when I try to install pydantic, in the traceback say's **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'** but in my requirements is specify the library.

Is there a form to install pydantic or is not possible install the library in Lambda's AWS?

#### Traceback in Cloudwatch

```
File "/var/task/app.py", line 5, in <module>
from pydantic import ValidationError
File "/var/task/pydantic/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
import pydantic_core
File "/var/task/pydantic_core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from ._pydantic_core import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'
[ERROR] Exception: Unable to import app.app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/wsgi_handler.py", line 115, in <module>
    wsgi_app = import_app(config)
  File "/var/task/wsgi_handler.py", line 48, in import_app
    raise Exception("Unable to import 
{}
".format(config["app"]))
```

I've tried downgrading the version of python, pydantic, Flask. I also specified the library pydantic_core and not working.

#### requirements.txt

```
Flask==1.1.4
Werkzeug==1.0.1
markupsafe==2.0.1
pymongo==4.5.0
pydantic==2.2.1
pydantic_core==2.6.1
email-validator==2.0.0.post2
```

#### serverless.yml

```
service: users

frameworkVersion: "3"

custom:
  wsgi:
    app: app.app

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.11
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2
  environment:
    MONGO_URI: <mongo_uri>

functions:
  api:
    handler: wsgi_handler.handler
    events:
      - httpApi: "*"

plugins:
  - serverless-wsgi
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

Comment: You must include dependencies with your code. This should help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-create-dependencies

Comment: I don't think this is enough.  It seems that pydantic_core library is architecture-dependent, and its not working correctly on the lambdas deployed by serverless framework.